# Gedit SyncTex Plug-In in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gedit, evince

I've upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 using the standard option of the ubuntu software installer, and the gedit synctex plugin stopped worked after that. It is hard to find out for me why -- it just does not work silently, without producing any messages.

What I've tried is: running gedit from the console and then after left-clicking with the Ctrl-key hold, which is supposed to trigger direct search, I get the following error on the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/synctex/synctex.py", line 104, in on_button_release
    self.sync_view(event.time)
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/synctex/synctex.py", line 195, in sync_view
    self.window_proxy.SyncView(self.gfile.get_path(), (line, col), time)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SyncView'
```

Inverse search from evince does not work either, but no messages are produced to the console.

I could not find anything similar by searching the web. Any ideas?

Comment: It was working for me in 20.04.. weird. This person has successfully used it in [18.04 as well.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1781559)

Comment: Gedit synctex plugin works with evince, which must not be installed from "Software Distribution" but from command line only.